# Why root created files get wrong permissions in samba share directory?

Tags: centos, permissions, samba

Whenever root user creates a directory or file it gets wrong permissions. I want so that every user in `sambashare` group could read and write in specified paths. This is permissions that directory gets when user creates directory: `drwxrws---.  2 sadmin sambashare 4096 Jul 29 02:20 dir1`. This is permissions that directory gets when system's root user creates directory: `drwxr-sr-x.  2 root   sambashare 4096 Jul 29 02:19 testdir1`. So I want to know why write permission drops after root takes action and how to avoid it.

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
workgroup = WORKGROUP
client min protocol = SMB2_02
client max protocol = SMB3
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = samba-server
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
inherit permissions = yes

[Spi]
path = /srv/servers/spi
force create mode = 0660
force directory mode = 2775
read only = no
valid users = @root @sadmin @sambashare
write list = sadmin

[Www]
path = /var/www
force create mode = 0660
force directory mode = 2770
directory mask = 2770
read only = no
valid users = root sadmin sambashare
write list = sadmin
[root@localhost samba]#
```

Edit

---

Files created through samba are okay, but files created locally through server's terminal (without connecting through samba) get wrong permissions.

```
[root@localhost ~]# umask
0022
[sadmin@localhost ~]$ umask
0002
```

Comment: Do you mean files created remotely through Samba, or files created locally? If it is the latter, please run the `umask` command as root and as the `sadmin` user, and edit the results into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why the permissions are set as they are?

When a Unix-style program creates a new file, it will specify initial permissions for it. These initial permissions specified are typically `0666` or `rw-rw-rw-` for regular files, and `0777` or `rwxrwxrwx` for directories or executable files. This is something coded right into each program and not easily changeable.

But these initial permissions will not be applied directly to the new file. The operating system will first knock out any permission bits that are set in the `umask` value. Your `sadmin` user has `umask 0002` which corresponds to `-------w-`, i.e. it only knocks out the write bit for the "other" users and allows all the permissions the program asked for the file's owner, and also for the user group the file belongs to. This results in permissions `rw-rw-r--` for regular files, and `rwxrwxr-x` for directories and executable files.

On the other hand, your `root` account has `umask 0022`, which corresponds to `----w--w-`, so it will knock out write access for everyone except for the actual owner of the file. This results in permissions `rw-r--r--` for regular files, and `rwxr-xr-x` for directories and executables. This is generally a good thing, as files that are owned by root but writeable by someone else can make some security exploits easier. This umask value will avoid creating such files by accident.

But why existing files may change as root edits them? Well, it depends on exactly what your text editor is doing. Some text editors will initially create a new temporary file (so that they will be able to save your changes if you're working remotely and the network connection is lost while editing) and when you "save" they actually just delete the original file and rename the edited temporary copy as the original. Some editors may maintain the permissions/ownership of the original file in the process, but not all of them. Some editors can be configured to do what you want.

### What can you do about it?

You could change root's umask to 0002 with a simple `umask 0002` command, for just that one session. Or you could add the command to appropriate shell start-up script, to make it persistent for root. But neither of these are really recommended, as that makes your root account more vulnerable to security exploits.

---

If your filesystem supports ACLs (and the support has been enabled by filesystem defaults or mount options - modern CentOS probably has it enabled by default), you can set a *default ACL* on the directory, which will effectively override the `umask` setting *for that particular directory only:*

```
 setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:o::rx /srv/servers/spi
```

Any new sub-directories created when this is in effect will automatically inherit the default ACL, just like what happens with the setgid bit.

If your share already has sub-directories, you might want to do this to all directories within the entire `/srv/servers/spi` directory tree:

```
find /srv/servers/spi -type d -exec setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:o::rx {} \+
```

---

As a yet another alternative, if you are following best administration practices you should not be logging in as root, so you are probably logging in with your personal account and then using `sudo` or `su` to become root.

You have already granted write access to this directory to the `sambashare` group, so you could simply add your personal account to the `sambashare` group, and then you would not need to be root to make changes in the shared directories - and for better accountability, you ideally *should not* make changes as root when you can do them using your personal account. If this system has audit logging enabled, then the audit logs in `/var/log/audit` will directly show who-did-what-when, which can be extremely important in some situations.

It is generally best to make the user groups & file permissions reflect the reality of who is allowed and expected to modify things, so everyone can do the normal day-to-day things using their personal user accounts, instead of routinely using the root account for everything.

Comment: Amazing explanation, THANK YOU!